# how to perform text manipulation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office

I need to do text manipulation of huge data which has column1 and 2 as given below.

```
example 
column1                  column2
Av heart LT of valve     heart LT of valve Av
Cc heart RT of valve     heart RT of valve Cc
Ab heart LT of valve     heart LT of valve Ab
Ds heart RT of valve     heart RT of valve Ds
Aq heart LT of valve     heart LT of valve Aq
```

I need to create column 3 as in example above.
I need to remove the first two words i.e AV and add them to end of  heart.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=MID(A2&" "&A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,LEN(A2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can create column 2 quite simply using `concat`, and concatenating all characters of column 1 except the first two, and putting them at the end:

[image]

You can see below the breakdown

[image]